# Null audio driver for windows 2008 r2?

Tags: windows, audio, device

I want to use an audio/video transcoding program on my server.

The solution that I found it's free and easy, so it fits my needs.

But... apparently that program needs an audio card to work. (I installed the user experience role for wmp and the windows audio service is running)

In fact when connected via RDP (audio streamed to the client), that program works perfectly.

So, since my server does not have an audio card, what I can do? There is a null audio driver for x64? If I install an driver for an hardware that I don't have, will it work?

PS: Virtual audio cable does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of Virtual Audio Cable. Version 4 does not support RDP but version 3 supposively does. Have you tried version 3?

http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac3.htm

Comment: i did not try, as i gave up on my idea....

Comment: will not work on server 2008. Anyway, thanks